# how do you disable toggle the items in the collection

Tags: modeling

[image] I cannot seem to find the button to enable me to disable the toggle function. My blender screen looks like this. When I have searched online, they need me to click a button that is similar to the flask. How do bring out the sign circled  I would greatly appreciate any assistance. Thanks for reading for all the help.

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to ask the question without being forced to watch any external tutorial videos? That would be very helpful. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks, first time asking on a platform.

Answer (score 0):

Either drag the left-hand edge of the outliner window to the left:

[image]

..or drag the toolbar itself to the left with the mousewheel button down:

[image]

Comment: Thanks I managed to do it. Really appreciate it .

Comment: Good. Please check my answer as accepted. Thanks.